# Container does not create beans Java EE

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, javabeans, application-server

I use:
GlassFish 6.2.5
openjdk-18
java ee 8.0.1

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestConfig extends Application {}
```

Here is my REST controller:

```
@Path("/sneakers")
public class RestSneakersController implements SneakersController {
    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("/findOne/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Sneakers getSneakers(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return dao.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

When I access his method via an http request, I get a 404 in response.

I checked whether the beans are being created by writing a message that should be output when an empty constructor is triggered.

```
public RestSneakersController() {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!CREATED!!!!!!!");
}
```

It is not output. From which I concluded that the bean is not being created. I have the same problem with Tomcat and JBoss. At the same time, there are no problems in the logs. I've been standing in the same place for a week now and I can't solve this problem in any way. The only hope is for you. Please help me.
Here is the link to [git](https://github.com/daliadaniele2002/fantastic-eureka/tree/Task-4/Microservice%20Java%20EE%20version/Sneakers_store/Sneakers_store_EE)

Comment: Why do you use a GlassFish ? Try to use Quarkus micro profile. It is same JEE!

Comment: @ArturTodeschini
And how do I add it to an existing project? On the Internet, I only saw the creation of a new project.

Comment: Don’t worry! You can migrate the legacy app to use quarkus, I migrate some… look this website to help you https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/12/migrating-java-applications-to-quarkus-lessons-learned